# AngularJs compiled options list template value="number:10"

Tags: angularjs

I've a "old" unit Test in jasmine where I test the selected Value from a dropdown with jQuery where I search for the selected attribute and get the coresponding value. The Last time I've run this unit tests I've just got a string with a single number back like "15" and the unit test runs fine.

now with angular 1.4.3 the Options rendered HTML looks like:

```
<option value="number:15" label="15">15</option>
```

now I need to check if the selected value is "number:15"

can someone tell me when this was invented in AngularJs and why? And I don't know whats the keyword to find any google result for this "issue".

Comment: can you reproduce the behavior in an isolated example?

Comment: here you can Inspect the dom on the angularJs documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions and ther you see e.g. value="object:3"

Answer (score 0):

No problem , do you have ng-model on your select element? 
just get the ng-model and compare it with a value. The selected value is saved on your model variable.

example:

**html**

```
<select ng-model="selectedtype" ng-option="types.id as types.descr for types in type">
</select>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.selectedtype='';
```

when youselect an item , the item id is going to go to the **$scope.selectedtype** variable, then you can do whatever you like.

Comment: I know. But I am interrested in the why they changed the behavoir and when.